# ReactJS - cannot read this.props.value on state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just starting to learn ReactJS and I have encountered an error upon compilation of my code:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

The error occurs on this line: `count: this.props.value` on the file `counter.jsx`
As you can see, I have tried to use `console.log(this.props)` on the render function on `counter.jsx` in order to validate if the props are set. They are set - so I do not know why I cannot access it in the state object in my Counter class. 
Question: What am I doing wrong?

**counter.jsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: this.props.value,
        tags: []
    };

    render(){
        console.log(this.props);
        return (<React.Fragment>
                    <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    formatCount(){
        var { count } = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? <h1>Zero</h1> : count;
    }
}
export default Counter;
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import Counters from './components/counters';

ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**counters.jsx:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';

class Counters extends Component {
    state = {
        counters: [
        {id: 1, value: 4},
        {id: 2, value: 0},
        {id: 3, value: 0},
        {id: 4, value: 0},
        ]
    };
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter key={counter.id} value={counter.value} selected={true} />))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counters;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` in `this.props` refers the object created by the JSX `<Counter {...}/>`. So to get an access of `this` of the instance of `Counter` class, you need to use `constructor` function.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    count: props.value,
    tags: []
  };
}
```

What you have right now to create the state, is pointing to the `Counter` class itself, not its instances, that is why `this.props` is `undefined`. You can do the same, without `constructor` function, with the help of [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) method.

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: null,
    tags: []
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {
      count: props.value,
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the state inside a constructor , I suspect `this` is broken

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    count: props.value,
    tags: []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside counter.jsx, add:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

You need to add a constructor with 'props' argument, and call super(props). To set state directly using props.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to set the value of state object directly from props. Better do:

```
state = {
    count: null,
    tags: []
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ count: this.props.value });
}
```

Comment: No need to do it inside `componentDidMount`, `constructor` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` is fine for this.

Answer (score -2):

if your would write it like so, i think it shoulk word. you write it this way to verify the value is existing on props, before you consume it.

```
state = {
        count: this.props.value ? this.props.value : null,
        tags: []
    };
```

Comment: Actually no, value is not undefined, props are , so this will still result in an error (regardless to the fact it has nothing to do with the error)